# Useful design patterns for working with FragmentManager on Android

Tags: design-patterns, android

When working with fragments, I have been using a class composed of static methods that define actions on fragments. For any given project, I might have a class called `FragmentActions`, which contains methods similar to the following:

```
public static void showDeviceFragment(FragmentManager man){
    String tag = AllDevicesFragment.getFragmentTag();

    AllDevicesFragment fragment = (AllDevicesFragment)man.findFragmentByTag(tag);

    if(fragment == null){
        fragment = new AllDevicesFragment();
    }

    FragmentTransaction t = man.beginTransaction();
    t.add(R.id.main_frame, fragment, tag);

    t.commit();
}
```

I'll usually have one method per application screen. I do something like this when I work with small local databases (usually SQLite) so I applied it to fragments, which seem to have a similar workflow; I'm not married to it though.

How have you organized your applications to interface with the Fragments API, and what (if any) design patterns do you think apply do this?

Comment: Why do you have one class responsible for showing all kind of fragment? Shouldn't it be a static method inside Fragment class inside?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted pattern is to have a factory method inside your custom fragment class (typically called newInstance() but hey dealer's choice).  So your fragment class should look something like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    public static MyFragment newInstance()
    {
        MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
        // add any bundle arguments here if needed
        return newFragment;
    }
    // rest of fragment class...
}
```

Then, when you create a fragment and add it to the backstack, instead of saying:

MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

You can use the factory method instead of the 'new' keyword.